# How to learn designing electronic cicuits?

Tags: books, reference

This is a soft question. I have completed my engineering in electronics discipline and unfortunately I still don't have proper idea of designing electronic circuits. But anyhow I want to clear this first and extremely important step of electronic hardware design engineer .

There are various basic components like R,L,C ,diode and other components like IC, Op-amps,micro controllers etc in the circuit. I wonder how circuits are designed for any application (you can consider any circuit of your choice) ?How particular values of such basic components are calculated ? How position of particular component is fixed  ?

Just for example say I want to convert 230V ac input voltage to 5V dc output voltage and 2A output current.I referred Texas Instrument's readymade circuit design which is obtained from webench design software. The circuit have step-down transformer, rectifier, different resistor,capacitors , transistors, fast switching diodes . So I don't understand how these perticular components and there values are selected? How these component are assembled to form a design?

I want to design and build electronic circuits myself. So can anybody tell me how to learn designing electronic circuits ? Are there any good blogs ,books, video series etc that can help me learning it?

Comment: Perhaps maybe what you are trying to ask is not coming across well. But it seems like you got your degree in electrical engineering, but don't know anything. Didn;t you have labs and assignments where you had to design something ? Amplify a signal with x gain ? That's a design.

Comment: @efox29 no, that's not the case. Say I want  to convert  230V ac input voltage to 5V dc output voltage and 2A output current. Then it will have  step-down transformer, rectifier,  different resistor,capacitors , transistors, fast switching diodes . So I don't understand how these perticular components and there values are selected.

Comment: Seems like you already aware of design. Since how do you know you need a step down transformer, rectifier etc.. How do you figure those out  ? Math. I think you know how to do those things already but maybe are looking for an easier step by step guide - which doesn't really exist. You know what the outcome needs to be, and you know how components work, so its a matter of putting them together. How do you design a voltage divider ? How did you do it ?

Comment: @efox29 I referred the circuit that was readymadely obtained from TI's webench design software. But I didn't understand there thinking behind the design for selection of components , positions and their values.

Comment: @user3559780 I think you just need to try to create your own stuff and then something will click in your head that relates what you learned in school with what you are trying to do. Right now it seems you are not relating how theory can be applied in practice. Just make stuff - anything. You'll figure it out :)

Comment: No,I didn't say you should just copy-paste,mind you,but use the basic designs to guide yourself through the task.It's up to you to decide upon how you modify it,how you filter signals and so on.Someone on this site said "Build a lot.Build circuits,read ,experiment".What is your task?Let's talk about it in chat:http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50786/discussion-between-user3559780-and-daniel-tork

Comment: **Study the work of others.** You need to acquire various mental models and this is the best way to force your mind into doing so.

Comment: "I have newly joined a small scale company and my boss wants me to design the circuit alone within 15 days without any help" - as a fresh graduate? With no senior EE experience in the company to help? You're doomed, AND they've seriously mismanged hiring you.  Which country is this in?

Answer (score 4):

Give your engineering school a "thumbs-up" - you've realized that your electronic education is incomplete, and never-ending.
For the practical aspect, [Dave's EEblog](http://www.eevblog.com/%20%22Dave's%20EEblog) is popular (and entertaining).
Many find "The Art of Electronics" by Paul Horowitz, Winfield Hill to be helpful in circuit design. It applies all the theory you learned to practical circuits.
Get a SPICE simulator too. A free one is downloadable for PCs:(LTspice).
And get a breadboard, and some measurement tools. Be prepared to learn from your mistakes - smoke is a great learning tool. My tin hat is on - folks are passionate about which aids helped them most, because learning is often frustrating and painful.

Comment: Also, keep looking at Application Notes and other electronic designs.  The Amateur Radio Handbook is a good source for circuits and explanations (and yes, "The Art of Electronics" is a great resource).  Try to figure out how these designs work.